# openpyxl loop through two spreadsheets match primary key and find differences

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Is there a way in python using openpyxl to loop through 2 spreadsheets and link them by a primary key and find the differences in a column. The example below uses "name" as a primary key and creates a new column with the differences

**example**

```
new.xlsx:
BOB, 1
JIM, 2
STEVE, 3

old.xlsx:
BOB, 100
STEVE, 200

results on new.xlsx:
BOB, 1, 99
JIM, 2, 0
STEVE, 3, 197
```

something like this

```
wb1 = load_workbook(r'new.xlsx')
wb2 = load_workbook(r'old.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
ws2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
for rowNum in range(2, ws1.max_row):
     ws1row = ws1.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value
     ws1row2 = ws1.cell(row=rowNum, column=2).value
     for rowNum2 in range(2, ws2.max_row):
         ws2row = ws2.cell(row=rowNum2, column=1).value
         ws2row2 = ws2.cell(row=rowNum2, column=2).value
         print ws2row
         if ws2row == ws1row:
         ws1.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value = ws1row2 - ws2row2
wb1.save(r'new.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. Create a third workbook to write the result
2. When you want to insert a new row you have to shift down every value of every cells bellow, and it can take a lot of time ...

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this in openpyxl. Import into a database and save yourself a lot of headaches.